# Cannot see debug log in output window after attach process in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have a website deployed to server, and I installed visual studio on that server. I attached process the iis website process to visual studio successfully.

In the output window (debug tab), I can see some logs. But I cannot see the logs which I wrote as `Debug.WriteLine("------------>" + ToObject(unencryptedItem).ToString());`

[image]

Do I miss any configuration to display the debug log under visual studio?